# Vuetify 1.5.x v-select dropdown styling

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using `Vuetify 1.5.24` and want to style the  dropdown popup that comes after clicking:
[image]

There is way to styling this component? every thing I'm trying is not success, including `/deep/`:

```
.v-menu__content /deep/ {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Show the html part

Comment: <v-select :items="purposeOfUseSelectOptions" v-model="purposeOfUse" solo></v-select>

Comment: U need to give element selector after /deep/ for it to work like .v-menu__content /deep/ .v_select_class {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

Comment: And check on chrome dev tools via inspect element to check if its taking tha css. If its not then try adding !important

Comment: How I add the ".v_select_class" class ?

Comment: You first need to check what class the v-select is using in chrome dev tools inspect element. Only then you can add the css in correct class/position. But to do so, you first need to identify the css selector of your need. It can be a tag name or class name.

Comment: This is the class I need to style: "v-menu__content theme--light menuable__content__active".
https://ibb.co/KzfbhXc
I think the problem is the "dropdown popup" is not part of the v-select html tree

Comment: Then you should do `div /deep/ .v-menu__content {}` or `div /deep/  .theme--light menuable__content__active {}` or `div /deep/ .v-menu__content  .theme--light menuable__content__active {}`

Comment: I think the problem is the "dropdown popup" is not part of the v-select html tree
https://ibb.co/q7kn8QZ

Comment: I see... Let me check if we have something like :host /deep/ or else we may have to add the css in App.vue <style> or maybe we can check if we can give a custom css class to v-select

Comment: I would say add the css in App.vue that's best and easiest way to do it because it has the root scope

Comment: Ok thx:) Maybe this problem with the Vuetify 1.5.x